# MongoDB conditionally upsert the latest record

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements, upsert

I have collection `col` with `name` as a unique key and below document

(I'm actually using dates for "D" field but for simplicity we'll use digits here)

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57bc79f2d3dd9e95d6ac2d4f"), "name" : "abc", "D" : 5 }
```

I want to do an conditional upsert as below,

name: "abc", D: 6 (update)

name: "abc", D: 4 (ignore)

name: "bcd", D: 10 (insert)

I tried below query in mongo shell

```
db.col.update(
   {"name":"abc","D":{$lt:6}},
   {
      $set:{"name":"abc","D":6},
      $setOnInsert:{"D":6}
   },
   {"upsert":1}
)
```

but it throws

```
"writeError" : {
                "code" : 16836,
                "errmsg" : "Cannot update 'D' and 'D' at the same time"
 }
```

Comment: can you remove $setOnInsert:{"D":6} and try.. what is happening here i think is that you have documents in the collection "col" with name="abc" and "D":6 and thus when updating these documents its giving you that error

Comment: I already have {"name":"abc","D":5} in the collection. your suggestion works if D:6 but if D:5 then it throws "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.col index: name_1 dup key: { : \"abc\" }"

Comment: I think you just said the other way round.. it works when you have {"name":"abc","D":5}  but when you run this the first time it gets updated to D:6 .. then when you run again it fails.. so that means it fails when D:6 and not D:5

Comment: also the $setOnInsert will insert the value only if its not present. if the field is present it will not insert

Comment: No it works when D:6 because the condition is true but not when D:5, which means "ignore" part is not working